# How can I persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xmodmap

This is working for the current session:

```
costales@dev:~/Desktop$ xmodmap -e "keycode 166 = less"
costales@dev:~/Desktop$ xmodmap -e "keycode 167 = greater"
```

Then I created this config file:

```
costales@dev:~/Desktop$ cat ~/.Xmodmap 
keycode 166 = less
keycode 167 = greater
costales@dev:~/Desktop$
```

But it's not working after a reboot. How could I force the remap to survive reboot?

Comment: Just answered this using `xkb` over here: https://askubuntu.com/a/960097/554991.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've been using 16.04 for a little bit and it seems to use sddm as its desktop manager. It used to be LightDM and GDM before that. Both its predacessors are documented to load `~/.Xmodmap` automatically but I can't find anything explicitly saying sddm does.

Therefore it may be advisable to just force it to load with a new script. You just need to run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` and you can do that a number of ways:

- Adding it via [the graphical start up tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459277/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-everytime-i-log-in-in-ubuntu-14-04)
- Editing `~/.xinitrc` to run it.
- Adding a new `.desktop` config in `~/.config/autostart/`

There are probably a few dozen other ways to manage this, essentially doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Add to start up didn't work and ~/.xinitrc doesn't exit. But append "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" to  ~/.bashrc worked! :)

Comment: Adding it via the graphical start up tools (which creates a new entry in `~/.config/autostart`) works about half the time. I've rebooted about 10 times now and 5 times the command has been executed and the other 5 times it hasn't. :-(

Comment: @Alexander Rechsteiner: This seems to be a problem in Ubuntu 16.04. I've been fiddling with startup commands and key remapping, and the behavior seems very inconsistent. I'm not an expert in this type of thing, but it seems utterly ridiculous for it to be happening...

Comment: Not working 20.04 .

Answer (score 27):

In my long experience with remapping keys in Ubuntu, the permanent solution is to modify a file called `evdev` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`.

Run this command in the command prompt.

`sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`

Remember gedit is a Ubuntu text editor so you can use nano or vim instead of gedit.

The file is in the format: ALIAS: CODE. You can swap buttons by interchanging codes of different keys. For example, to swap RCONTROL with RETURN, edit two lines in evdev into this:

`<RTRN> = 105;`

`<RCTL> = 36;`

To know the number code for a button run `xev` on the terminal.

Log out and back in to apply changes.

Comment: I think this might the easiest way to permanently remap a key. I just did that successfully on a Ubuntu 18.04-based distribution, replacing my dead up arrow key by the right shift key. Thanks!

Comment: I found that guide particularly helpful when editing `evdev`: https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/xkb.html

Comment: And, yes, in Ubuntu 19.10, the `xmodmap`-based solution doesn't work persistently for me, as some background process(es) randomly runs `setxkbmap` and resets everything. Placing `xmodmap` in .xinitrc or so doesn't seem to fix that.

Comment: @Mario Yep! It doesn't. What I would do is to place all the xmodmap commands in a single file and then execute all the commands in the file at once on bootup.

Comment: HOORAY! I've been struggling with this for hours, and this is what finally worked. In my case I wanted my web key to be my menu key, so I made `<COMP> = 180` and commented out the line where `<I180> = 180`. Downside is that if I plug in a different keyboard, the real Menu key won't work, but the compact keyboard I'm using doesn't have one at all.

Comment: @WillMatheson Yes! Very true. The changes will affect all keyboards. What you could do is to have two keys do the same thing so that the old menu key and the new assigned menu key both point to the same value

Comment: Works just fine! Though it might be obvious to some, I had to reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: @AlejandroCamus, Really! I don't recall rebooting when I changed the keys

Comment: @GilbertS I am using an Ubuntu virtual machine, would that matter?

Comment: Do we need restart after changes?

Comment: UPVOTED! Only working solution on the web for 20.04.Well done!

Comment: works amazing (after trying several unreliable workarounds) on Pop!_OS 20.04 to remap "home, end, pgup, pgdn, del" on Keychron K4 v1

Comment: This was the only thing that allowed me to remap Search to Caps_Lock on my Chromebook running Ubuntu.

Comment: how do you remap fn?

Comment: Usually you can't remap fn - https://askubuntu.com/questions/827925/remapping-the-fn-key

Comment: After days of web surfing, this Sh!t worked on Ubuntu 20.04. Its so simple and minimal in comparison to what I tried so far! Its dumb easy in Windows. But on Ubuntu, we gotta try so many things just to realise it wont work!

Answer (score 9):

I added a file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/80_xmodmap` with these contents:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Set custom keycodes
#
# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.
# The "|| true" is to ensure that the Xsession script does not terminate on error

USRMODMAP="$HOME/.Xmodmap"

if [ -x /usr/bin/xmodmap ]; then
        if [ -f "$USRMODMAP" ]; then
                /usr/bin/xmodmap "$USRMODMAP" || true
        fi
fi
```

This works every time.

Comment: It appears to work but this is the messages I get in .xsessions-errors: .Xmodmap:1:  bad keysym in remove modifier list 'Caps_Lock', no corresponding keycodes
this is my .Xmodmap:
$ cat .Xmodmap 
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 9 = Escape
keycode 66 = Escape

Comment: Your error message seems clear: You have an error in your ~/.Xmodmap file

Answer (score 5):

open gnome-session-properties. add command and name. desktop file will be created in ~/.config/autostart.

remenber: use **absolute path**, eg /home/xxx/.Xmodmap. never use '~' as your home dir.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Startup Applications and make a new entry with the content shown in the following screenshot:

[image: adding new startup application(command)]

It works every time.

Comment: Thank you! this worked like magic and it's super simple!

Comment: This is the simplest one, even in older and newer Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

After searching on Google, I was able to resolve my laptop faulty keys remapping. All faulty keys on my Thinkpad T400 are working fine after remapping. Also, it's permanent without an extra load on the CPU core.

- First find your keyboard layout or keycode using below command.

  ```
  xev -event keyboard
  ```
- For example, on my Thinkpad T400 keycode found as follows:

  ```
  Keycode of "z" key is 52
  Keycode of "x" key is 53
  Keycode of "c" key is 54
  Keycode of "v" key is 55
  Keycode of "F6" key is 72
  Keycode of "F10" key is 76
  Keycode of "F11" key is 95
  Keycode of "F12" key is 96
  ```
- Remapping character keys "z" "x" "c" "v" by assigning function keys "F6" "F10" "F11" "F12".
- Modify lines as below (Backup file before making any changes to rollback easily if things go wrong).

  ```
  sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
  ```
- Find the lines and change value as below:

  ```
  <AB01> = 72;
  <AB02> = 76;
  <AB03> = 95;
  <AB04> = 96;
  ```
- Comment these lines or remove the lines:

  ```
  //  <FK06> = 72;
  //  <FK10> = 76;
  //  <FK11> = 95;
  //  <FK12> = 96;
  ```
- Save and exit.

To remap special keys:

- Backup file before making changes to rollback if things go wrong.

  ```
  cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/

  sudo vi pc
  ```
- Add or modify below lines in function "xkb_symbols "editing" {"

  ```
  key [SCLK] {    [  Prior        ]   };
  key [PAUS] {    [  Next         ]   };
  ```
- Save and exit.
- Clear cache.

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
  ```
- Reboot.

Comment: I remapped a broken (cursor) arrow key to another key using this technique. It's simply (xev) and press new key to get its scancode, then edit /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev to replace the arrow key's original keycode with the new keycode and to remove the new arrow key's line with its original scancode. I commented wherever I made a change and kept a backup of the file. After a reboot it works perfectly, including shift/ctrl/alt combinations with the new arrow key. And the change should be left in place even when upgrading packages and OS version upgrades.

Comment: The only method that's actually persisted from hibernate, restarts and turning off and on my keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
```

With sudo privileges, in an editor, open the layout you desire to edit. Replace the values.

After reboot, the changes will be applied.

---

Here is an example I use to remap my keypad because of keyboard hardware issues.

[keypad remap example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmpv8.jpg)

Comment: Those edits will be overwritten the next time the packages that owns those files get upgraded.

Comment: That may be true, but I doubt these specifically are updated very often. I have been satisfied with this solution for some months since I solved the issue and not once did I have to do anything additional. And to prevent this, you can save the file and replace it in the case of such event or, (which seems more secure) just recreate the process.

Comment: I found that this was the best way to persist the changes too. xmodmap seemed to forget the mapping as soon as I even disconnected my keyboard for whatever reason. This solution isn't perfect but works. We'll see how it goes. @Sanalgorithm's answer above instructs on how to do the remapping alluded to here.

Answer (score 1):

### Graphical Editor

`gnome-tweaks` > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options

[image: Key Maps]

Answer (score 0):

Because .Xmodmap files are much easier to edit than xkb, I **use .Xmodmap as a 'source' file, then convert it to xkb** (the current standard) and auto-load at boot using the .bashrc method.

It's a few simple steps posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/858272/165265).

Works perfectly, and using xkb future-proofs against when support for .Xmodmap is dropped.

Comment: Why do you think support for xmodmap will be dropped?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up  @OlafDietsche. Just completed upgrades to 18.04.3 on 3 machines and was surprised to find xmodmap support not only returned, but better than before. So I'll update the link and the above post w/ current info. Best to you.