# Remapping the `fn` key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macbook

***Please note**: This is not a duplicate as the <kbd>fn</kbd> key behaves differently than other keys on the keyboard. I can't get the <kbd>fn</kbd> keycode by using, for example, `xev`.*

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook now, with UK keyboard layout for input, which works fine and has all the keys in the correct positions.

The one thing I never got used to on my Macbook is that the <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys are swapped over from what you would usually see in most UK laptops' keyboard layouts.

[image]

Can I reconfigure my keyboard layout in Ubuntu so that the <kbd>fn</kbd> key in the picture above becomes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and vice-versa (while keeping all others keys exactly the same)?

This is tricky because the <kbd>fn</kbd> key doesn't seem to behave like other keys. *You can't get the <kbd>fn</kbd> keycode by running `xev`.* Every other answer to this question I've found doesn't apply when dealing with the `fn` key, as they depend on getting the keycode from `xev`.

**How can I remap <kbd>fn</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and vice-versa?**

I will welcome any "hackish" idea or solution.

Comment: Fn keys generate ACPI events and not keyboard events. `sudo acpi_listen` and press a Fn + volUp will show `button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K`. It connects directly to the hardware so is OS independent. Remapping probably is out of the question.

Comment: Take out the *probably* and make it an answer.  It's brilliant and concise as it is.

Comment: I finally found something that works for me: https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched

Answer (score 14):

Fn keys generate ACPI events and not keyboard events. To echo the keypress for Fn to the terminal use ...

```
sudo acpi_listen
```

Pres Fn + F12 and it will show

```
button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K.
```

This connects directly to the hardware and is OS independent. Remapping  is out of the question.

Here is an [interesting read](https://jablonskis.org/2012/linux-and-samsung-series-laptop-9-fn-keys/) about kernel and a keymap. But that goes beyond a basic changing of keycodes and it does not deal with setting the control key to act as an Fn.

Comment: How can I remap which fn combinations correlate with actions?

Comment: On Arch: `sudo pacman -S acpid && sudo systemctl start acpid && acpi_listen`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm late to the party.

Since you are using an Apple keyboard, you can use the [free5lot's hid-apple-patched](https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched) to swap this two keys, and also perform a couple of other remaps (`fnmode`, `swap_fn_leftctrl`, `swap_opt_cmd`, `rightalt_as_rightctrl`, `ejectcd_as_delete`).

It works with the built-in keyboard and also with magic keyboards

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched#installation-via-dkms-recommended) are pretty straightforward.

P.S.: I personally just tested it with US layouts, but should work with UK variants as well.