# is there a way to findout the keycode of a specific key in ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: keyboard

[How to disable keys from the keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54417/how-to-disable-keys-from-the-keyboard/1027267#1027267)

i want to disable a key and my question is beeing aswered in the linked thread. however i have an additinal question:

is there a way to findout the keycode of a specific key in ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `xev` should do the trick. If I'm remembering right you can find it in the `x11-utils` package. Run xev and press the keys you want, it'll spit out a bunch of info for each event:

[image: Example of xev output]

For *just* keyboard events, you should launch it in a terminal with `xev -event keyboard` to tell it to ignore non-keyboard events like mouse moves.

Comment: Don't you mean `xev -event keyboard`?

Comment: Oddly enough it seems like both work just fine. But yeah, man page refers to `-event`.

Comment: `xev -e` seems to also work, perhaps `xev` just checks the first letter.

Comment: the answer also seems to be answered in the linked thread. guess i need to sleep. however it does not work i want to find the keycode for FN+f10. i dont need to press FN because its being pressed automaticly(uefi).

Comment: [code]KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  65  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  65  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
[/code]

Comment: @hanswurst31 In that case you should try the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/827953/495653 and see if that works. Most `FN`-based keypresses aren't treated as normal keypresses.