# key-mapping - Workaround for keyboard with missing keys (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, shortcut-keys, xkb

My thinkpad has got a few of its keys damaged, and I have been trying a permanent workaround for it. I tried using xmodmap which could set the <kbd>F9</kbd> key to the letter "L" (small/caps based on whether or not <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed) but it couldn't persist beyond a reboot. [Permanent xmodmap in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04) says that there's a different way to do this for 16.04 as xmodmap has to be manually loaded after every boot.

However, I realised that <kbd>F9</kbd> could be an important function key at certain situations, so I want to set up something like <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> == <kbd>l</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> == <kbd>L</kbd>. I couldn't figure out a way to do this with the above link. Would be really helpful if someone could help me out, I'm a complete beginner. It's really tiring to click on OnBoard every single time.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solved it for me : [How persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-persist-a-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

1. Once I made changes to `xmodmap` using the key codes from `xev`
2. I edited `.bashrc` and added the line `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this: http://www.fsays.eu/Blogging/Blog/Details/23.

The `/dev/uinput` device in Linux allows you to create a virtual keyboard. You'll then need a piece of software to accept keystrokes from your real keyboard and turn them into these virtual keys. Googling for "`/dev/uinput` virtual keyboard" should get you started.

Comment: If you were to expand this answer with an actual method for arriving at a solution you might get the bounty as @scienceauror can't self award it.

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't have an actual method. But I've done it before and there will be many solutions on Google.

Comment: Just a suggestion.