# ubuntu 16.04 keyboard remap suddenly doens't work

Tags: keyboard-layout

I've asked a question about remapping the keyboard by using xmodmap, and I refered a question below and it helped some:
[How persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04)

but unlike that question, my xmodmap rewinds though I didn't reboot or logged off.
Does anyone know why the xmodmap suddenly doesn't work? I can't get the circumstance that makes it back to normal.

For some information about my problem, I need to change Alt_L and ISO_Level3_Shift. So this is my .Xmodmap file:

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
remove mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = Alt_L
keysym Alt_L = ISO_Level3_Shift   
add mod1 = Alt_L
add mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

In sum, I can remap the keyboard by using the .Xmodmap file above, but it rewinds although I didn't reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to change Alt_L and ISO_Level3_Shift, I think this command does what you want:

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_alt -option lv3:lalt_switch
```

If it does, you can make the change persistent for your user via this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_alt', 'lv3:lalt_switch']"
```

Comment: Thank you. Sadly the first one doesn't work. The second one works well, but it doesn't change it persistently.

Comment: Sorry it works :)