# Reset faulty key mapping

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

While remapping keys I accidentally did something to change the behavior of my alt keys. If I have a window open and I press alt the window is grabbed and stuck to the cursor/arrow keys. This makes my frequent use of alt-tab useless.

The major change I made was with xmodmap, although I don't think this is the cause as they changes are reverted every time I reboot (I added a line to my `.bashrc` to set my new mappings but this does not take effect until I open a terminal). I also have a backup of my original mapping which I used to reset my changes but that did not fix the issue.

Another change I made in an attempt to persist my xmodmap changes was to add a file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/802493). However, this did not work so I removed the file. I also tried creating a .xinitrc as explained in the top answer on that post but also subsequently deleted that.

None of the above changes explain my problem so I suspect that I deleted or edited something along the way and forgot about it.

Extra Details: 
Running `xmodmap -pke` shows nothing funny for keycode 64 (left alt):

```
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
```

The only shortcut mapped to either Alt key is Alt L to `Key to show the HUD.` Changing this to another key combo (temporarily to alt q) did not fix the issue.

Plugging in an external keyboard verifies that it is not a hardware issue (the behavior is the same with the external keyboard).

What I have tried:

- Resetting my keyboard layout with `setxkbmap -layout us -option`
- Resetting shortcuts with `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`

I apologize for my rather vague details; I'd be happy to provide any more detail if needed.

Comment: Try `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a go, but alas, it didn't work.

Comment: I ended up fixing it! The issue was that I had several keyboard shortcuts which began with `alt` under `settings > keyboard > shortcuts > windows`. I think it was `move window` in particular, which had the shortcut `alt f7`. I have no idea how this got set in the first place but removing the entry by clicking on it and pressing backspace fixed it. This does not explain why `alt` on its own was doing the action for `alt f7` but I suspect that is due to my water damaged keyboard.