# 16.04: Desired key remapping won't load at startup

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard, xorg, remapping

Running Ubuntu 16.04. I got a compact keyboard without a Menu key. They included a bunch of fluff keys, so I want to make the "web" (XF86HomePage) key be my Menu key. (One can run `xev | grep keycode` to find key names and codes by pressing the keys.)

I can:

- Execute `xmodmap -e "keycode 180 = Menu"` in a terminal. This works fine for the rest of the session.
- Save a file `~/.Xmodmap` with the content `keycode 180 = Menu` and execute `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`. This also works fine for the rest of the session.

But I have not been able to get this to happen without my intervention at startup, which is what I want. I've tried adding a script to "Startup Applications" but no joy and I've also gone so far as to edit my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc file to include:

`key <XF86HomePage> {[ Menu ]};`

but all that did was make my keyboard not work at all after rebooting, and I had to come back and undo the change with a rescue disc.

Advice and insight, as always, much appreciated.

Comment: `key <I180> {[ Menu ]};` in that "pc" file may well have worked! Worth trying sometime when there aren't a bunch of other things on the go.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Back to the evdev file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to do, per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161870/870100), is to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` and reboot. I made `<COMP> = 180` (`<MENU>` is an alias for `<COMP>`) and commented out the line where `<I180> = 180`. Downside is that if I plug in a different keyboard, the real Menu key won't work, but the compact keyboard I'm using doesn't have one at all and it's not an absolutely necessary key anyway (if you have a mouse) so I'm good with this.