# Right click + left click acting as a middle click

Tags: mouse

So not too recently ago I have noticed that if i use left and right click at the same time i activate a middle click. Some games are unplayable because of this. I want to know how to disable this because I can't find an answer online that works with Ubuntu mate.

Thanks -an ubuntu lover

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable middle click emulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620964/disable-middle-click-emulation)

Comment: You may check https://askubuntu.com/questions/597064/disabling-middle-mouse-button and https://askubuntu.com/questions/620964/disable-middle-click-emulation

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, i fixed it by plugging my mouse into a different usb port. maybe this will help, i just wanted to let you know what worked for me.